# image_url not working within action mailer (Ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, view, actionmailer

I added the following in my production.rb environment file.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: "domain.com"}
```

## In my view:

```
<%= tag("img", src: image_url("logo.png"))  %>
```

However, when I look at the path in my email, I see a image_path, not URL.

http:///assets/logo.png

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it works in my application. Try this

```
<%= image_tag(attachments['logo.png'].url, style: 'margin: 5px') %>
```

Comment: Needed to add this to the mailer: attachments.inline['logo.png'] = File.read(Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/logo.png')), then your code worked.  Thanks for the lead!

Comment: attachments['logo.png'] = File.read(data.logo.current_path) for dynamic url. And iwas assuming you are doing this. If my answer help then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`asset_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_path) instead of `image_url` in production email views.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `config.action_mailer.asset_host = "domain.com"` in production.rb. Then use `image_tag` in your mailer view.